# Create stored procedure to add new column based on other column in table (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm new to SQL and attempting to write a stored procedure that will do two things.

1. Add a new column to a previously-created table.
2. Populate this new column with data based on another column in the table.

I can get it to add the column, it's part two where I'm really having trouble.

Basically, I don't understand how to say, "If the value in this slot is higher than x, alter the value to this. Otherwise, alter the value to this."

I could do this in any other language, but SQL just doesn't resonate well with me.

Below is basically what I'm trying to create. The first two lines work, sort of. I didn't know how to say, "Read from this column, do the check, then put the discounted value into the new column." My thought was to copy the values from the other column into my new one, then alter it from there.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ProductLineSale
AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE Product ADD SalePrice DECIMAL (6,2)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE Product SET SalePrice = ProductStandardPrice';

    IF SalePrice >= 400 THEN
        SalePrice := SalePrice*.85;
    ELSE
        SalePrice := SalePrice*.90;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: By the way, the purpose of saving code as a stored procedure is so that we can reuse it multiple times, but an `alter table` statement can only run once, so this procedure will never work after the first time. Perhaps it should be an anonymous block. Also, the code you have posted is [PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/overview.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can directly use your logic in your update statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ProductLineSale
    IS
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE Product ADD SalePrice DECIMAL (6,2)';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE Product SET SalePrice = 
            case when ProductStandardPrice >= 400 THEN ProductStandardPrice*0.85 
                 ELSE ProductStandardPrice*0.9 END';

    END;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add a virtual column to your table (Virtual column: "[values are derived rather than stored](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1)") eg

**Table and data**

```
create table products ( productstandardprice number( 6, 2 ) ) ;

insert into products ( productstandardprice )
select level * 199.99
from dual
connect by level <= 5 ;
```

**Query**

```
SQL> select * from products ;

PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE
--------------------
              199.99
              399.98
              599.97
              799.96
              999.95
```

**ALTER TABLE**

```
alter table products
add (
  saleprice number( 6, 2 ) generated always as (
    case
      when productstandardprice >= 400 then
        productstandardprice * .85 
      else
        productstandardprice * .90
    end
  ) virtual
) ;
```

Same Query as before ...

```
SQL> select * from products ;

PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE  SALEPRICE
-------------------- ----------
              199.99     179.99
              399.98     359.98
              599.97     509.97
              799.96     679.97
              999.95     849.96
```

**PROCEDURE**

```
create or replace procedure productlinesale
is
begin
  execute immediate ' 
    alter table products
    add (
      saleprice number( 6, 2 ) generated always as (
        case
          when productstandardprice >= 400 then
            productstandardprice * .85 
        else
            productstandardprice * .90
        end
    ) virtual
  )' ;
end ;
/
Procedure created.


-- caution: this needs the "original" table (without the virtual column)
begin productlinesale; end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Query for testing**

```
SQL> select 
  2    productstandardprice
  3  , saleprice
  4  , round( saleprice / productstandardprice, 2 ) as factor
  5  from products
  6  ;

PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE  SALEPRICE     FACTOR
-------------------- ---------- ----------
              199.99     179.99         .9
              399.98     359.98         .9
              599.97     509.97        .85
              799.96     679.97        .85
              999.95     849.96        .85
```

Tested w/ Oracle 11g and 18c.  Dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3351852bc04ccd37e6ace44463b820fe).

Comment: This would probably be the best solution in the real-world, but my professor doesn't really live there. I'm not even allowed to use joins in my work because...reasons. Thank you very much for your advice, though!